# Why can't I create an object greater than 2GB in size in .NET, even on x64?

Tags: .net, memory, memory-management, 64-bit, memory-limit

After reading [Are C# Strings (and other .NET API’s) limited to 2GB in size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106945/are-c-strings-and-other-net-apis-limited-to-2gb-in-size) I played around with large strings and arrays in .NET 3.5. I found that the largest array I could allocate was `int.MaxValue - 56` bytes. Similar thing for strings: the largest I could get was `(int.MaxValue - 58) / 2` characters (since each character took 2 bytes). After that it throws `OutOfMemoryException`.

**Why does this limitation exist?** Not that I've ever run into it in practice - I'm just curious about the inner workings of .NET.

Yes, this was on a 64-bit machine with plenty of RAM, of course - and yes, the process was running as a 64-bit process. (I could actually allocate 3 such arrays or strings for a total memory usage of 6GB.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a design decition to restrict the size of an object on the GC Heap to 2GB, even on x64. Good blog post on it here from one of those involved in the design decision:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/joshwil/bigarrayt-getting-around-the-2gb-array-size-limit)

Comment: Thanks. That confirms that it was a conscious design decision, though it doesn't really explain why they made that decision.

Answer (score 2):

In versions of .NET prior to 4.5, the maximum object size is 2GB. From 4.5 onwards you can allocate larger objects if [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is enabled. Note that the limit for `string` is not affected, but "arrays" should cover "lists" too, since lists are backed by arrays.