# Are there any collection classes or special data types that support more than 2 ^ 31 items in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, collections, 64-bit

I am currently using VS 2008 64 bit edition, 3.5 framework with SP1.  However, it appears that the collection classes like List have a limit of 2^31 (or max value of an int) elements that it can contain.

Does anyone know if there are any true 64 bit collections that can handle more than 2^31 elements within a container?  If not for VS 2008, then what about VS 2010?  Any 3rd party collections out there that do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need this? It is a ridiculously large amount to store, and you'd probably use too much memory anyway.

Comment: if you have to deal with that much entries... i suggest you use a DataBase instead.. that would be more easy and will have greater performance..

Comment: What criteria are you looking for in a collection?

Comment: *Related:* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106945/are-c-strings-and-other-net-apis-limited-to-2gb-in-size

Comment: *Also related:* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657181/very-large-collection-in-net-causes-out-of-memory-exception/3657189#3657189

Comment: Thanks for the links.  The reason why I am interested in collections or arrays with > 2GB is because I am in the process of writing an article on using the binomial coefficient to minimize memory usage and have designed a class to use the List<T> class, which has a limit of 2GB entries.  For some potential users of this class, it will not be enough.  To overcome this limitation, it looks like the Mono C# compiler or using a specialized collection can be used to handle more than 2GB elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am pretty sure there are no builtin collections that can handle more than `Int32.MaxValue` entries. The reason is because the .NET Framework still has ~2GB limit for objects even for the 64-bit version. `Int32.MaxValue` entries of one byte bumps up against this limit. I believe Mono's memory limit is larger, but I cannot definitely confirm that.

You can work around this limitation using the `BigArray` implemenation from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the BigArray article. I was not aware of Mono, which is a C# open source project which does appear to support arrays and collections larger than 2GB along with some other functionality that MS C# compilier does not support according to this link:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)