# which .net collection can contain more than Int32.MaxValue elements?

Tags: .net, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any collection classes or special data types that support more than 2 ^ 31 items in .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005660/are-there-any-collection-classes-or-special-data-types-that-support-more-than-2)

which .net collection can contain more than Int32.MaxValue elements?

List can only hold Int32

Comment: Are you sure you are able to fit it into the memory?

Comment: Why do you need such a collection in the first place?

Comment: Why for god's sake would you want such a big collection?

Comment: An application that contains a collection that holds more than Int32.MaxValue elements needs more than 2 GB of memory for this collection alone.

Comment: Also related, but not dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657181/very-large-collection-in-net-causes-out-of-memory-exception/3657189#3657189 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906891/what-is-the-max-limit-of-data-into-liststring-in-c/3906931#3906931.