# What is the Max size of Two Dimensional character array?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have one two dimensional array:

```
char[,] DataFile;
```

When I create a object:

```
DataFile=new char[45000,6000]
```

It throws an *out of memory exception*.

What is the Max Size of object in .Net 3.5? What Is the Max Length of char array?

Comment: Are you building as x86 or x64?

Comment: I don't know, but I do know that what you appear to be doing (keeping a large file entirely in memory) is rarely what you need or want to do. I recommend you use IO streams to dynamically access and buffer the parts of the file you currently require.

Comment: It all depends on the amount of memory

Comment: You are allocating about 1 GB of memory, on char is 4 bytes.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391672/what-is-the-maximum-size-that-an-array-can-hold)

Comment: Also, have you tried googling it? https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+max+object+size gives me loads of SO posts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Single objects still limited to 2 GB in size in CLR 4.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087982/single-objects-still-limited-to-2-gb-in-size-in-clr-4-0)

Comment: @Casperah: char is 2 bytes (Unicode)

Comment: I read that In Net 4.5 we can allocate memory more than 2 gb Is It right?

Comment: @JeffRSon: Sorry, you are right, so the allocation is 500 MB then.

Comment: @Casperah: Maximum object size is 2 GB (prior to .NET 4.5), so the largest possible array of chars would 2^30 (a little more than a billion). Assuming, of course, that you could find a large enough contiguous block of memory (unlikely on a 32 bit machine).

Comment: Can anyone able to give me solution of above problem?

Comment: I check in x64 but same problem.

Comment: @MaheshChitroda How much available RAM do you have in your computer?

Comment: @nmat I have 2 GB RAM.

Comment: @MaheshChitroda Do you have 2GB RAM available or 2GB RAM total? Run "Windows Task Manager" and see how much free memory you have before and after running the program.

Comment: I have 2 GB RAM total.

Answer (score 2):

[Single objects still limited to 2 GB in size in CLR 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087982/single-objects-still-limited-to-2-gb-in-size-in-clr-4-0) already has quite a nice explanation of the limits in various circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends.

Obviously it'll matter how much physical memory (RAM) you've got installed and/or how large you set up virtual memory (swap).

In any case, in 32bit Windows maximum object size is 2GB. But there's another limit: The process image must have a contiguous block of memory of the required size.

Your array is about 514MB large. You should check for yourself if you have sufficient resources available.

Answer (score -2):

There is no actual limit, it just depends on how much RAM your computer has, and how much contiguous memory the runtime can allocate.

Comment: this is false please check source before posting

Comment: I was answering based on ur current case, your not affected by the 2gb issue, and the array index length issue, so ur only limitation is ur own memory