# I need very big array length(size) in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, size, biginteger

```
public double[] result = new double[ ??? ];
```

I am storing results and total number of the results are bigger than the 2,147,483,647 which is max int32.

I tried biginteger, ulong etc. but all of them gave me errors.

How can I extend the size of the array that can store > 50,147,483,647 results (double) inside it?

Thanks...

Comment: Do you really have 373 gigabytes of RAM?

Comment: Sounds like you need a different data structure.

Comment: Definitely an XY Problem

Comment: if I use that much of page file, yes :)

Comment: Do you really need all of that data in memory? Why not just offload it to a database?

Comment: @AtikBayraktar: Applications cannot run directly out of the page file; it is only use to page out inactive processes.

Comment: @SLaks i want array with 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 element.can i do it??

Comment: @AminM: You don't have enough memory to do that.

Comment: @SLaks It's funny in year 2023, in situation processing very large image and pointcloud data, the number of pixel or point in a single file more than Uint32.MaxValue(array index type implemented in .net) is so common. As people may think 32bit address of memory is more than enough in 20th centry :)

Answer (score 15):

An array of 2,147,483,648 `double`s will occupy 16GB of memory.  For some people, that's not a big deal.  I've got servers that won't even bother to hit the page file if I allocate a few of those arrays.  Doesn't mean it's a good idea.

When you are dealing with huge amounts of data like that you should be looking to minimize the memory impact of the process.  There are several ways to go with this, depending on how you're working with the data.

---

#### Sparse Arrays

If your array is sparsely populated - lots of default/empty values with a small percentage of actually valid/useful data - then a sparse array can drastically reduce the memory requirements.  You can write various implementations to optimize for different distribution profiles: random distribution, grouped values, arbitrary contiguous groups, etc.

Works fine for any type of contained data, including complex classes.  Has some overheads, so can actually be worse than naked arrays when the fill percentage is high.  And of course you're still going to be using memory to store your actual data.

#### Simple Flat File

Store the data on disk, create a read/write `FileStream` for the file, and enclose that in a wrapper that lets you access the file's contents as if it were an in-memory array.  The simplest implementation of this will give you reasonable usefulness for sequential reads from the file.  Random reads and writes can slow you down, but you can do some buffering in the background to help mitigate the speed issues.

This approach works for any type that has a static size, including structures that can be copied to/from a range of bytes in the file.  Doesn't work for dynamically-sized data like strings.

#### Complex Flat File

If you need to handle dynamic-size records, sparse data, etc. then you might be able to design a file format that can handle it elegantly.  Then again, a database is probably a better option at this point.

#### Memory Mapped File

Same as the other file options, but using a different mechanism to access the data.  See [`System.IO.MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) for more information on how to use Memory Mapped Files from .NET.

#### Database Storage

Depending on the nature of the data, storing it in a database might work for you.  For a large array of `double`s this is unlikely to be a great option however.  The overheads of reading/writing data in the database, plus the storage overheads - each row will *at least* need to have a row identity, probably a BIG_INT (8-byte integer) for a large recordset, doubling the size of the data right off the bat.  Add in the overheads for indexing, row storage, etc. and you can very easily multiply the size of your data.

Databases are great for storing and manipulating complicated data.  That's what they're for.  If you have variable-width data - strings and the like - then a database is probably one of your best options.  The flip-side is that they're generally not an optimal solution for working with large amounts of very simple data.

---

Whichever option you go with, you can create an `IList<T>`-compatible class that encapsulates your data.  This lets you write code that doesn't have any need to know *how* the data is stored, only what it *is*.

Comment: To the person that edited my answer because "SSDs are commonplace now, random reads being much slower is hardly an issue anymore" the answer is not improved by removing the parts you changed.  My data center storage isn't entirely SSDs and sequential is still faster than random reads due to read-ahead optimization.

If you have a better answer, add it yourself.

Comment: To add to Corey's note, many server and desktop appliances still use hard drives for bulk storage, which your program may be running on or operating upon data stored on. You shouldn't make assumptions about the user's hardware unless you are willing to dictate them (e.g. minimum specifications).

Answer (score 5):

BCL arrays cannot do that.
Someone wrote a chunked [`BigArray<T>` class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx) that can.

However, that will not magically create enough memory to store it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Even with `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`, the maximum size of any dimension in an array (of non-`byte`s) is 2,146,435,071

So you'll need to rethink your design, or use an alternative implementation such as a jagged array.

Comment: Why 2146435071? Why not 2147483647?

Comment: @NayukiMinase I don't know, but it is what it is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is to implement your own BigList.  First note that List is implemented as an array.  Also, you can set the initial size of the List in the constructor, so if you know it will be big, get a big chunk of memory up front.

Then

```
public class myBigList<T> : List<List<T>>
{

}
```

or, maybe more preferable, use a has-a approach:

```
public class myBigList<T>
{
   List<List<T>> theList;
}
```

In doing this you will need to re-implement the indexer so you can use division and modulo to find the correct indexes into your backing store.  Then you can use a BigInt as the index.  In your custom indexer you will decompose the BigInt into two legal sized ints.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I solved it using a list of list which mimics very well an array but can go well beyond the 2Gb limit. Ex List<List> It worked for an 250k x 250k of sbyte running on a 32Gb computer even if this elephant represent a 60Gb+ space:-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

C# arrays are limited in size to `System.Int32.MaxValue`.

For bigger than that, use `List<T>` (where T is whatever you want to hold).

More here: [What is the Maximum Size that an Array can hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391672/what-is-the-maximum-size-that-an-array-can-hold)

Comment: You're aware that a `List<T>` is backed by an array yes?