# Datatypes for MemoryStream.Capacity vs MemoryStream.Length

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream

Today I noticed something strange with the [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. The [`.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.length(v=vs.110).aspx) property is a `long`, but the  [`.Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.capacity(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which should presumably always be `>= .Length` is only an `int`.

I know that it would take a stream of over a GB to for Length to exceed possible Capacity, but this seems very strange to me.  `Length` can't be changed, because it's inherited from `Stream`, but why not make `Capacity` a `long` as well?  What happens to the capacity if you *do* have a `MemoryStream` that exceeds `int.MaxValue` in length?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `MemoryStream.Capacity` can't exceed the `int.MaxValue` because memory stream is backed by a `byte[]` and [arrays maximum length is `int.MaxValue`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391672/what-is-the-maximum-size-that-an-array-can-hold).

However, `Stream.Length` is `long`, that makes sense because stream can be anything, For example `FileStream.Length` can be greater than `int.MaxValue` undoubtedly.

Answer (score 3):

A fundamental limitation in .NET, unfortunately, is that objects cannot exceed 2GB in size. The `Stream` class needs the `long` for its `Length` property, because a `Stream` can represent a resource outside of .NET (e.g. a file), but since `MemoryStream` is known to always be an in-memory, managed object, it is guaranteed to always be able to fit its `Capacity` in an `int`.

Comment: FWIW, .NET Framework 4.5 allows creating arrays larger than 2GB on 64 bit platforms by setting [`gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) inside `app.config`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov There are still limits on the number of _indexes_ to the big array though, which are a bit smaller than 2^31 (detailed in your link). The ``MemoryStream`` will still only be able to hold a bit less than 2GB with that switch enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The `Length` property is inherited from `Stream`, while the `Capacity` property is declared for `MemoryStream`. Streams in general may be larger than 2GB, but this particular kind of stream never will be -- hence, the `Capacity` that is specific to `MemoryStream` is just an `int`.