# Maximum Array size equals RAM size?

Tags: arrays, memory, virtual, ram

I am just curious about the array size of any programming language prefereably which can allow high size. after reading this link

[What is the Maximum Size that an Array can hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391672/what-is-the-maximum-size-that-an-array-can-hold)

is it that the Maximum array size is equivalent to RAM theoretically?, as RAM has to work on other application etc also. Or can we increase the virtual memory to accommodate any size of array.

Comment: Arrays can be in virtual memory rather than RAM, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: if in virtual memory can we specify an array of 30GB or more?

Comment: On a 64-bit machine, if you have that much virtual memory to spare, sure. 32-bit machines are more limited. But then there's the limitations of the OS and language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depend on ram size, and ram is constantly consumed and released back.so u can not figure how much for sure u can utilize. If theratically speak. If only array and ram then yes keeping every thing e.g os and programs out of question.