# Why do I get System.OverflowException when init array

Tags: c#, exception

```
byte[] buffer2 = new byte[4294743227]; // string with System.OverflowException
```

The number 4294743227 is uint.

Why do i get exception?

Comment: that is nearly 4 gigs of storage!

Comment: i wouldn't use a `uint`, try using `long`.

Comment: @maccettura, yes ofc.

Comment: @DanielA.White Actually, it's closer to 16 gigs. He's trying to allocate more than 4 billion ints, each of which occupies 4 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391672/what-is-the-maximum-size-that-an-array-can-hold), the maximum size of an array is [`System.Int32.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), which is 2,147,483,647.

See also the documentation on [`System.Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx):

> By default, the maximum size of an Array is 2 gigabytes (GB). In a
>   64-bit environment, you can avoid the size restriction by setting the
>   enabled attribute of the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects configuration element
>   to true in the run-time environment. However, the array will still be
>   limited to a total of 4 billion elements, and to a maximum index of
>   0X7FEFFFFF in any given dimension (0X7FFFFFC7 for byte arrays and
>   arrays of single-byte structures).