# Memory overflow

Tags: c#, memory

```
  List<int> pal=new List<int>();
        List<int> nums = new List<int>();
        var thdigit1 = 1;
        var thdigit2 = 999;
        while (thdigit2>=1)
        {
            var holder=thdigit1* thdigit2;
            nums.Add(holder);
            thdigit2 -= 1;
            if (thdigit2==0)
            {
                thdigit2 = 999;
                thdigit1 += 1;
            }
        }
```

I am getting a memory overload problem for too much in the list. Is there a certain limit that my computor can handle? Thanks

Comment: Since your computer is probably no infinite machine: yes there definitly is a certain limit. But there maybe a problem in your code. See Ian's answer.

Comment: along with referring to below answer kindly read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So i belive for this problem the list should contain 999^2 ints in the list, is that too many?

Comment: Please do not come up with custom description of errors - provide error *exactly* as reported by compiler/runtime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009217/whats-the-max-items-in-a-listt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when `thdigit2` is `1`, it is still continuing the `while` loop,

```
while (thdigit2>=1)
```

reduced by `1` and then becomes `0`

```
thdigit2 -= 1;
```

and... reseted back to `999`.

```
if (thdigit2==0)
{
    thdigit2 = 999;
    thdigit1 += 1;
}
```

Thus you get memory overflow as you never gets out of the `while` loop.

To fix it, you probably need to add another termination condition in your `while` loop:

```
while(thdigit2 >= 1 && thdigit1 <= 10) //example
```

Comment: The purpose of the code was to create all possible combinations of two three digit numbers.

Comment: I am really stupid, thanks for the answer. First time asking a question and was inexperienced.

Comment: @Kieran no problem. :) everybody must start somewhere..