# How can I create a list that has a length of a 64 bit unsigned integer in c#?

Tags: c#, list, 64-bit, blockchain, ram

I am trying to create a blockchain based cryptocurrancy in c#. I have my blockchain class built but I realize on big problem with the current implementation. The blockchain is stored in memory in a List>. The problem I see with this is that the length of the list is a 32 bit signed integer. This is a problem if the chain get too big. Is there a way of making a List<> that has a maximum length of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

The current way of storing the blockchain is by initializing

```
static Dictionary<string, Socket[]> connections = new Dictionary<string, Socket[]>();
```

and adding a new Dictionary for every block

Comment: Please see related question [What's the max items in a List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009217/whats-the-max-items-in-a-listt)

Comment: Can you post some code?  It sounds like creating a list using unsigned int for the type.

Comment: I'm unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: "or do I have to stream the chain from a file" You should be doing that even if a list could be larger than 2^31 items long.  That's a *massive* amount of memory, that you appear to not even need at all, if streaming isn't a problem.  You should always be streaming the content of any non-trivially sized file, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear what are you asking in question but from your title it sounds like creating a list using 64bit unsigned integer.

You can use [`ulong`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ulong) that is a 64bit unsined integer ranging from `0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615` and create a `List<T>` of `ulong`

```
var myList= new List<ulong>();
```