# what is difference between 32 bit and 64 bit .net frameworks max memory?

Tags: .net, frameworks

is there difference between max memory 32 bit and 64 bit .net frameworks? I mean: can I allocate more than 2GB memory when writing on 64 bit .net framework?

what is features of 64 bit .net framework? I cant find it on internet.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/1087982/38206

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfx64bit/thread/9d89adec-3eed-469e-8a81-1365e48e92a1) post, it looks like they removed the max 2GB and you can use all memory available.

> x64 has the following pros:
>
> 1. No 2GB memory limit - you can use all of the memory available.
> 2. Potential for better perf., especially with some double precision
>      math.  x64 has a couple of extra
>      registers, and can do some things
>      faster (potentially).  I've seen some
>      significant boosts in some highly
>      numerical code, but for most business
>      applications, you won't see a
>      difference.
>
> x64 has the following cons:
>
> 1. Less than ideal IDE support
> 2. Program takes more memory (object references 2x size)

Looking at [Migrating 32-bit Managed Code to 64-bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx) might be helpful as well.

Comment: IIRC the limit is 3GB if you enable the 3GB switch on the PE

Comment: Re "IDE support" - that is less true all the time. There are some tools that are still problematic, but for most things: fine.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: True, and if I understand http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff556232.aspx correctly, the limit will even be 4GB for 32-bit processes on a x64 system (from Windows Server 2003 SP1 on).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can allocate as much memory as your system will allow before crumpling under the weight - however, arrays (which includes most lists) and strings etc are still limited to 2GB. Note also that since the size of a reference doubles, this means you can only have *half* as many references in a list. But that is still **a lot** of references.

The sizes of `int` etc don't change, since they are fixed regardless of the platform.

You may also see other oddities - x64 and x86 have some different optimisations in the engine. So please do test - don't just change it to x64 and blindly deploy. Examples here would be [tail call](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2007/06/20/tail-call-jit-conditions.aspx) and various things surrounding complex cases like `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, in practice, the program uses almost twice as much memory on 64 bit system. No other issues so far. (Mine is a set of ~30 windows services crunching some data using an ORM -- hence the many object references).