# C# big string array to string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, performance

I have a string array of about 20,000,000 values.
And i need to convert it to a string

I've tried:

```
    string data = "";
    foreach (var i in tm)
    {
        data = data + i;
    }
```

But that takes too long time

does someone know a faster way?

Comment: Why do you need one single `string` that large?

Comment: I'm working on making a zipper for school

Comment: Why do you need a string that large, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You might want to look at this [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c).

Comment: Performance is bad because `data = data + i` is a [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Comment: I'm not sure what all you need to do for your zipper, but there must be a way to accomplish it without creating a gigantic string.

Comment: for such a large concatenation you need to look at other options, like streaming to disk for instance

Comment: Just tell us if this is for real.. If it is, tell us what is the source of these millions of strings. Why loading them into memory at the first place? Use the source to compress, if that is what you mean by a zipper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is going to depend on the size of the output string and the amount of memory you have available and usable.  The hard limit on string length appears to be 2^31-1 (`int.MaxValue`) characters, occupying just over 4GB of memory.  Whether you can actually allocate that is dependent on your framework version, etc.  If you're going to be producing a larger output then you can't put it into a single string anyway.

You've already discovered that naive concatenation is going to be tragically slow.  The problem is that every pass through the loop creates a new string, then immediately discards it on the next iteration.  This is going to fill up memory pretty quickly, forcing the Garbage Collector to work overtime finding old strings to clear out of memory, not to mention the amount of memory fragmentation and all that stuff that modern programmers don't pay much attention to.

A `StringBuiler`, is a reasonable solution.  Internally it allocates blocks of characters that it then stitches together at the end using pointers and memory copies.  Saves a lot of hassles that way and is quite speedy.

As for `String.Join`... [it uses a `StringBuilder`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,92).  So does `String.Concat` although it is certainly quicker when not inserting separator characters.

For simplicity I would use `String.Concat` and be done with it.

But then I'm not much for simplicity.

Here's an untested and possibly horribly slow answer using LINQ.  When I get time I'll test it and see how it performs, but for now:

```
string result = new String(lines.SelectMany(l => (IEnumerable<char>)l).ToArray());
```

Obviously there is a potential overflow here since the `ToArray` call can potentially create an array larger than the `String` constructor can handle.  Try it out and see if it's as quick as `String.Concat`.

Answer (score 3):

Try [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var i in tm)
{
    sb.Append(i);
}
```

To get the resulting `String` use `ToString()`:

```
string result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks but i get the following error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: @SerhatReis Be aware that even in an x64 environment [there is 2 GB limit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6107351/205233).

Comment: @Filburt the very next (and much more recent) answer on the link you provided states that the 2GB limit doesn't apply to x64 as of .NET 4.5...

Comment: @DrewJordan The limit still applies but can be disabled.

Comment: @DrewJordan The 2GB limit is for objects.  In the latest x64 frameworks it is relaxed, but strings can still only hold at most `int.MaxValue` characters.  Strings use `int` internally for lengths so they can't ever exceed 2^31-1 characters in length.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do it  in LINQ, like such.

```
string data = tm.Aggregate("", (current, i) => current + i);
```

Or you can use the string.Join function

```
string data = string.Join("", tm);
```

Comment: The `Aggregate` you have is basically the same thing and will have the same horrible performance.  The `Join` is OK, but `string.Concat` would make more sense.

Comment: I am really curious about the metrics of each solution. I don't expect much from linq myself this way, and probably will calculate the metrics for each to settle my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Cant check it right now but I'm curious on how this option would perform:

```
var data = String.Join(string.Empty, tm);
```

Is `Join` optimized and ignores concatenation a with `String.Empty`?

Comment: `Join` doesn't appear to make any special allowances for empty separators.  They have a `Concat` method for that case, so I guess they didn't think it was necessary to test for it in `Join`.

Answer (score 0):

For this big data unfortunately memory based methods will fail and this will be a real headache for GC. For this operation create a file and put every string in it. Like this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("some_file_to_write.txt")){
    for (int i=0; i<tm.Length;i++)
        sw.Write(tm[i]);
}
```

<strike>Try to avoid using "var" on this performance demanding approach.</strike> Correction: "var" does not effect perfomance. "dynamic" does.

Comment: Why not use `var`? It is resolved at compile time so should have zero impact on performance.

Comment: @Corey Thanks for asking. It was my mistake to mix `var` with `dynamic`. I've corrected it.

Comment: All good.  I figured it was either a mistake or something I wasn't aware of.  Was actually hoping it was the latter :)