# How to add new item to the x:Array from Window.Resources programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this XAML code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Name="arrayXAML" x:Key="WordList" Type="sys:String">
      <sys:String>Abraham</sys:String>
      <sys:String>Xylophonic</sys:String>

      <sys:String>Yistlelotusmoustahoppenfie</sys:String>
      <sys:String>Zoraxboraxjajaja</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>
```

I know that I can access this array by both of these lines of c#:

```
Object res1 = this.Resources["WordList"];
wordList = this.FindResource("WordList") as string[];
```

But what about if I want to add a new string to the x:Array programmatically?

I have tried: `arrayXAML.Items.Add("hello");` but it doesn't seem to work when I then use the "FindRescource" as shown above. Is there a way to add items to this array?

Comment: You could instead use an observablecollection https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26200.wpf-dynamicresource-observablecollection.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XAML `x:Array` is represented with `ArrayExtension` class.

See `x:Array` on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-array-markup-extension):

> In the .NET Framework XAML Services implementation, the handling for
>   this markup extension is defined by the ArrayExtension class.

It is important to understand, that **what you have/get in/from your `ResourceDictionary` is not an `ArrayExtension` but `string[]`**.
So run-time changes on `arrayXAML` you will not see in the `ResourceDictionary`.

**You can't add new element to the `string[]`**, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976898/how-do-i-expand-an-array-in-c-sharp-without-using-the-new-keyword), but what you can is to set new value in the `ResourceDictionary` for key `WordList`:

```
var sarr = this.Resources["WordList"] as string[];
var newSarr = new string[sarr.Length+1];
for (int i = 0; i < sarr.Length; i++)
{
    newSarr[i] = sarr[i];
}

newSarr[newSarr.Length-1] = "New string from code behind";          
this.Resources["WordList"] = newSarr;
```

Remark: Since you are modifing the resource, then do use a `DynamicResource`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{DynamicResource WordList}"/>
```

Comment: @mm8 You can't add an element to the __existing__ instance of array. Resize method creates new instance and copy elements to it. Just not with `for` loop.

Comment: Your are wrong. See [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,71074deaf111c4e3)

Comment: You are absolutely correct. It does create a copy. My bad. (+1)

Comment: @mm8 I admit, that it is a vile trap with changing only of the local variable by Array.Resize.