# Large Objects and .NET (x64): The Meaning?

Tags: .net, memory-management

I've been reading about the ~2GB size limit of objects in .NET, and sadly feel that I must be missing something. I believe I have created Lists that are larger than 2GBs, and in so far as a List is an object...I am confused. Could someone explain to me what they mean by this limitation?

Comment: *mutters various curses at MS* Ok, post that as the official answer. ;-)

Comment: lots of good detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087982/single-objects-still-limited-to-2-gb-in-size-in-clr-4-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total space taken by all of your dereferenced objects may have exceeded that. But the space requirement for the list and its internal pointers to each object it contains were less than 2 GB.

To expound upon this general concept - the pointers themselves are relatively small in terms of storage requirement.  The objects to which they point can individually be very large (or very numerous).