# Does Visual Studio 2012 Express have limits on reading large files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Here's my code to read a text file, which happens to be larger than 1GB and is pipe-delimited:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string strFilePath = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\123.txt";

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var arrRawData = File.ReadLines(strFilePath).Select(line => line.Split('|')).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button I get this error:

> "System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

I have 16GB of RAM...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line gives you this error?

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087982/single-objects-still-limited-to-2-gb-in-size-in-clr-4-0

Comment: [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx) may be helpful..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your program is operating in 32-bit mode.  Which will never permit reading more than about 650 megabytes of data, about the largest size hole available in the address space.

Project + Properties, Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option.

Do note that using this much memory is still unnecessary in almost any app that parses file data.  Just read one line at a time with the StreamReader class.

Comment: "using this much memory is still unnecessary", oh, I don't know ;p I've written plenty many things that make use of all that system memory

Comment: I unticked "Prefer 32-bit" option.  When running the program I now get the error: "Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program'(path of program'\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe'.  Unrecognized error occurred in the Windows Web Services framework.   When I re-tick "Prefer 32-bit" the program runs okay (albeit before I click the button).

Comment: I'm choosing this answer because it mentions using StreamReader instead.

Answer (score 1):

there is no limit imposed by visual studio. you may have 16G but you cannot use all of it for your program. try using a stream or not reading the whole file at the same time but rather line by line...

Answer (score 0):

When running your program error occures: **"Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program. Unrecognized error occurred in the Windows Web Services framework.**

the solution is turn off your firewall. Firewall bloks:

```
Event: Traffic
IP Address/User: 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
Description: Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (devenv.exe)
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Message: Blocked Outgoing TCP - Source 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 :  (12276)  Destination 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 :  (12275)
```