# Large file as embedded resource in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to add a large file (3.6gb) as an embedded resource in Visual Studio 2012. Is this possible? 
I've tried with files ~1gb as well and they fail too. Already have a few other files ranging from 5-60mb and they work fine.

Getting this error message when compiling:
**Error 2 Unexpected error writing metadata to file 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.**

(Running win8 x64, loads of ram and disk space. Seriously doubt that's where the problem lies..)

Comment: Just curious, why you have to embed 3.6G into assembly?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, **why**?

Comment: `EXE File` with 3.6Gb embedded resource = 3.6Gb+ `EXE File`.... EPIC...

Comment: Are you wrapping a full HD movie?!

Comment: Just because you're working in 64 bit Windows doesn't necessarily mean you can have 64 bit single objects.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087982/single-objects-still-limited-to-2-gb-in-size-in-clr-4-0

Comment: It's an installer of sorts, first thought that struck on how to get it to work the way I wan't was to try to embed it :) Anyways, sounds like it's not really possible, so will go with another approach.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio is a 32 bit program. It can only use 3 GB (max) memory, regardless of how much memory you've installed. You see, that's exactly why I wanna see a 64 bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Don't embbed such a large file, it will cause problems to the compiler!
Add it as a linked resource.

Comment: While I agree with the "don't do it" part, this doesn't answer the question (which problems are you talking about?)

Comment: I didn't even know you had the option. It's just locked at linked resource for non-media (pictures, music, etc) files.