# What is the largest array I can create under .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, .net-4.5

I'm experimenting with memory limits on my x64 machine (Windows7) under .NET 4.5. Based on [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) (as referred to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9640656/93394)) it seems like I should be able to create an array with up to `UInt32.MaxValue` elements. So I enabled `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` and tried to create the following array:

```
int[] arr = new int[UInt32.MaxValue]; //2^32
```

However, this generates an OverflowException: ("Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.")

So I tried this instead,

```
int[] arr = new int[UInt32.MaxValue/2];   //2^31  (i.e., 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```

and it throws a 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.

What am I missing here, and what in fact is the largest integer array that I can create?

---

**UPDATE:** So, as it turns out, the largest array I can create is:

```
int[] arr = new int[(long)(1.999 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)]; //just shy of 2^31
```

So why can't I reach the limit that the documentation leads me to expect?

Comment: Did you thought that "the fact" can not be reproduced in your environment?

Comment: At run time it would depend on how much contiguous addressable memory you have available, and the size of the thing in the array.

Comment: I'm pretty sure windows, by default, limits the program to 2GB of memory.  I think there are ways around that.

Comment: @MikeH: You're thinking of 32-bit Windows, the Q clearly says x64.  And the 64-bit .NET compilers certainly don't do anything so stupid as clearing the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag in the PE header (which would limit even a 64-bit program to 2GB)

Comment: @BenVoigt ...I must learn to read...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your link:

> The maximum index in any single dimension is 2,147,483,591 (0x7FFFFFC7) for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures, and 2,146,435,071 (0X7FEFFFFF) for other types.

You're exceeding that limit, still.

This should give a darn big array, though:

```
int[,] arr = new int[UInt32.MaxValue/3,3];
//                 comes out even ^^^
```

The total size of that array, which contains the maximum number of elements, should be (16 GB - 4 bytes + metadata)  Use an even larger value type to really put the hurt on your PC.

Comment: you would think that the compiler would object to int[uint.maxvalue] since it is clearly wrong

Comment: @pm100: There is, of course, cost associated with adding a compile error for that.  As Eric Lippert likes to remind us, a specification has to be written and approved, the code has to be written, and then it has to be tested.  Also, the compiler hasn't any way to know whether `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` will be in effect when the program runs, so it can't actually know what limit to enforce.  A much better option would be a clear message in the exception... it could say what is exceeded, the overall array size, the total number of elements, or the size of a single dimension.

Comment: @pm100 is it actually wrong according to the C# specification or the CLS specification? It seems more like this is a current implementation limitation. Array.LongLength is there for 64 bit array indexes after all.

Comment: Excellent, Ben. I just didn't read the docs close enough, I guess. Brilliant example with the 2D array to clarify the distinction between the number of elements and the size of the index. THank you!